# Как отсечь лишние цифры без округления?

Tags: python, pandas

У меня в данных есть столбец, в котором 5 значные числа.
Мне нужно создать другой столбец, в котором из этих 5 цифр будут браться только первые две и без округления.

Например - в исходном столбце значение 66959
В новом мне нужно чтобы было 66

Заранее благодарю

Comment: `df['b'] = df['a'] // 1000`.

Comment: Благодарю!!!! Получилось! @StanislavVolodarskiy

Answer (score 2):

Делайте что-то в таком роде:

```py
table['b'] = table['a'] // 1000
```